# $X_1$, $X_2$ i.i.d., prove that $E(X_1\mid X_1+X_2) = E(X_2\mid X_1+X_2)$

Tags: probability

I got to the point where I only need to prove that for every $h$ Borel,

$$E( h(X_1+X_2) (X_1-X_2) ) = 0$$

This is obvious when $h$ is the identity function, but I don't know what to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $E(h(U+V)U)$ depends only on the joint distribution of $(U,V)$. Apply this to $(U,V)=(X_1,X_2)$ and $(U,V)=(X_2,X_1)$.

Comment: $E(h(X_1+X_2)X_1)=E(h(X_2+X_1)X_2) \Leftrightarrow E(h(X_1+X_2)X_1)−E(h(X_2+X_1)X_2)=0 \Leftrightarrow E(h(X_1+X_2)(X_1−X_0))=0$

Answer (score 1):

If $W_1,W_2$ have the same joint distribution as $X_1,X_2$, then $E(W_1\mid W_1+W_2)$ should be the same as $E(X_1\mid X_1+X_2)$.

Apply that to the case where $W_1=X_2$ and $W_2=X_1$.